# WAStorageEmulator.exe start failure

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I just installed the Windows Azure SDK. It came with Version 3.0 of the Windows Azure Storage Emulator. When I tried to launch the emulator it initializes successfully (after prompting me for system admin password) but it fails to start (again, after prompting me for system admin password).

The exception that I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: Unable to open wait
>   handle. at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.EmulatorProcessController.InternalWaitForStorageEmulator(Int32
>   timeoutInMilliseconds)

My current user is not a system admin but I do have the password to a system admin account.

Anybody run into this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage emulator requires a one-time initialization run with elevated privileges. By using a different user to elevate, it looks like the emulator may have initialized for that user only. You need to run initialization as the current user but with elevated privileges. Once the emulator is initialized for the user, you will not need elevated privileges to run the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I made my current user an admin. Signed out, signed back in. Re-ran the emulator and it worked!

Comment: I'm running ".\wastorageemulator start" from an admin powershell terminal. Can you tell me in more detail what you mean with setting current user to admin? I believe my system is already admin :S

Comment: I running the app in administrator mode didn't work for me. I had to physically add my user to the administrators group in order for the emulator to properly setup.

Comment: my pc has only one user and it is the administrator.. still the same problem